# Accidentally created Java application instead of JavaFX

Tags: netbeans, javafx

Using Netbeans 8.0.1, I have created a simple Java (ant) project instead of a JavaFX project. Is it possible to convert this project to a JavaFX project? In that case, how do I do that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which JDK version are you using?

Comment: I hava javafx in my netbeans but i started my project as a simple Java application and not as javafx application.Now i would like to add a chart that supported for javafx in my project and i can't because the code don't recognize javafx.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 8, the JavaFX classes are on your classpath.
You can just create a class that extends javafx.application.Application and implement the start(Stage stage) 
and 
main (String[] args)
methods.

Next, in Project Properties go to the "run" tab and select your new class as "Main Class"